# Store a value and compare it with a new one

Tags: python

I'm working in a python script runner and I've been trying to find a way to store a value and then compare itself after a few seconds. This is my code so far :

```
  initialexp = game.GetCharEXP()
    print initialexp

import time
print 'Waiting 5 seconds to check changes on Initial EXP'
time.sleep(5)

if initialexp == final exp:
    exit()
```

`game.GetCharEXP()` is a function included in the software (when I print it it shows the value).

`exit()` is another function included in the script runner.

so, what I want is store `game.GetcharEXP()` value into `initialexp` and then compare it 5 seconds later with `finalexp`  variable and make a loop of it (so it checks it every 5 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a while loop and then break out of it when the values match.

```
import time
while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    if initialexp == finalexp:
        break
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to store the game.GetCharEXP() so I can compare it in the next 5 seconds.

For example:

initialexp = 50

wait 5 seconds

finalexp = 80

so I'm using the same function and the value of this function will change, so I need to store it into variables to make a comparison after 5 seconds.

Comment: Just call the function at the top of the while loop and store it as a variable.  Each time the loop restarts, it will call the function again and then you can make a comparison with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
while True:
    initialexp = game.GetCharEXP()
    time.sleep(5)
    if initialexp == game.GetCharEXP():
        # Exp did not change within 5 seconds so perform an action
```

Comment: in order to know what the final exp is, I have to take the value from GetCharEXP again (since it's a comparison from the same variable.

Comment: Don't you have to know what the upper boundary is for `finalexp` or are you trying to determine what finalexp is by finding the point at which `game.GetCharExp()` stops changing?

Comment: game.GetCharEXp() will never stop changing unless an specific situation happens. I want to know when it stops for 5 seconds or more so I can change print a warning.

Comment: I updated my example to reflect your comment.  Does that look correct?